# How to add a new command line variable to an existing construction Environment?

Tags: build, scons

Suppose I have a `SConstruct` which exports a construction environment to a subsidiary `SConscript`:

```
Export('SConscript', 'env')
```

I'd like for `SConscript` to insert a command line variable `foo` into `env` so that I can invoke builds with the command

```
scons foo=bar
```

Is this possible, or must support for such command line variables be supplied to the environment's constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `Variables` object containing the new variable and then update the environment`in the subsidiary`SConscript`:

```
Import('env')
vars = Variables()
vars.Add('foo', help='a command line variable named foo')
vars.Update(env)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that understand question clearly, but my answer is.

Scons have very good support for command line parameters. In your case use function `ARGUMENTS.get('command_line_parameter', [default])`. To insert variable into environment just use index operator `[]`.

Example :

```
env['foo'] = ARGUMENTS.get('foo') # if parameter not set, returns None
```

or with default value :

```
env['foo'] = ARGUMENTS.get('foo', 'bar')
```

You can found more information about [command-line parameters handling](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c2092.html) in scons guide.

Answer (score 0):

You may also pass command-line values to environment, when updating it with variables:

```
vars.Update(env, ARGUMENTS)
```